# Issue when Input and write HTML Code into a Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, browser, textarea

I have a small form that has a TEXTAREA to write some HTML email template.

When using my own localhost (WAMP), it works ok, but when online, depending on HTML code it send me back to login page and all SESSION variables seems to gone away... Only when my code has some href, style tags, etc...

If I don´t type some  codes, style codes or hrefs it works ok.

I found something about browser issue, but not sure if is this case...

I cannot even reach the action page when typing some codes... but no errors appears. It goes directly to index page.

Any idea?

```html
<form id="formcontato" name="formcontato" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="modelo.php">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="codigo">Código</label>  
<div class="col-md-2">
 <input id="codigo" value="<?= $estemodelo->codigo; ?>" name="codigo" type="text"  class="form-control input-md" required="" onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" maxlength="10">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="texto" style="text-align:left;">    </label>
<div class="col-md-12">            
 <textarea rows="20" class="form-control" id="texto" name="texto"><?= $estemodelo->texto; ?></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
<div class="col-md-12">
 <button id="submit" name="submit"  class="col-md-12 btn btn-primary">   Gravar   </button>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

More information:

I´m testing as a dummy... inserting one html code line by line to see if it writes...

I´ve typed some lines and works ok, but when type the following code, it goes to index.php file... I have some records with a lot of lines more (contracts with 10 pages and simple Html codes and ok)... so, this is not a field size problem.

Look at this simple snippet:

If I only rip off the body style tag, it writes ok... if trying to type with body style tag, the problem happens...

```html
</head><body style='background: #eee;font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;overflow-x: hidden;text-align: center;'>
<div id='container'><div class='container-fluid'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm'><div class='logo' style='text-align:center;padding:30px;'>
<img src='http://myimage.png' alt='' title='' width='150'></div>
<h2 style='text-align: center;font-size: 1.5em;text-shadow: 2px 2px #eeeeee;text-align: center;padding: 0 0 10px 0;margin: 0;'>
```

Comment: There's no database code in this sample as far as I can tell. Is that relevant to the problem? If so, edit and include that part.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to know exactly what your issue is here

Could you

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION)
echo "</pre>";
```

and

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($estemodelo)
echo "</pre>";
```

before this form on the online version and update the answer to show what it says?

**edit:** Previously I mentioned to change the echo'd output to concatenated to tidy it up but removing this to avoid confusion as this wouldnt fix the problem.

Based on your updated answer

> If I only rip off the body style tag, it writes ok... if trying to type with body style tag, the problem happens...

it maybe the single quotes in the body style getting broken by the font-family. Try this

```
<body style="background: #eee;font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;overflow-x: hidden;text-align: center;">
```

Comment: Why do you think he needs to make that change? PHP expands variables inside double-quoted strings.

Comment: It shows the following variables:
<code>
Array
(
    [TEMPO] => 1531169456
)
Modelo Object
(
    [id] => 14
    [codigo] => TESTE-ALE
    [descricao] => TESTE
    [texto] => 
)
</code>
But I don´t think it is this case... if I don´t type any html code that hrefs something, works ok...

Comment: This is a common misconception about how PHP strings work. Instead of switching to concatenation, use `title='{$estemodelo->id}' ...` to ensure that the values interpolate properly.

Comment: I think we are loosing focus... the problem isn´t what the variables shows... I use same php file as action and it even reaches same file... I´ve already put a single code  as above:

<code>
<?php echo $_POST['texto']; 
exit; 
?>
</code>
but even reach it depending what I type at textarea...
It is some issue regarding browser / php...

Comment: I mentioned he should change it just so it was more readable as its concatenated later in the same output. Removing this part of the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks Oli Girling... code cleaned... ripped off what doesn´t matter...

Comment: Glad that helped A.Gaeta, please accept the answer if that helped